# appelées ou dénote

Tags: vocabulaire

Dans un rapport, j'aimerais éviter la réptition dans le rapport entier. 
J'ai un seul type d'encre, une encre en provenance d'un projet Atlas.

Question : comment annoncer cela ?
Ma proposition :

```
Les encres Atlas, appelées seulement encres dans la suite du document, sont des ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La façon que vous utilisez pour énoncer cette particularité de votre texte convient très bien. « Dénoter » ne va pas du tout car il ne s'agit pas de notation. Il y a d'autres possibilités ;

- Les encres Atlas, auxquelles je réfèrerai dans la suite du document seulement par le terme « encres », sont des ..
- Les encres Atlas, terme abrégé dans la suite du document par le terme « encres », sont des ..
- Les encres Atlas, abrégé dans la suite du document par le terme « encres », sont des ..
- Les encres Atlas, que dans la suite du document j'appellerai simplement « encres », sont des ..